# Yii assigns return of require? Help to understand

Tags: php, yii, return, return-value, require

I just found the following piece of code in Yii MessageCommand.php

```
    $config=require($args[0]);
    $translator='Yii::t';
    extract($config);
```

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/cli/commands/MessageCommand.php Line 82

I thought require could only return true or false.

Could anybody enlighten me about this snippet please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's return variable from included scope (if there is 'return' statement):

```
//index.php
$a = include('a.php');
echo $a;//12

///file a.php
<?php
return 12;
```

Comment: OK, didn't know about the return. Thanks!!